# Not able to forward traffic from `tun` interface to `lo`

Tags: go, networking, vpn, http-proxy, tun

> Originally asked here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56278/not-able-to-forward-traffic-from-tun-interface-to-lo

I am writing a small VPN server, in which for a certain ip address, I am passing the traffic through an `http proxy`.

### Current Setup

- TUN interface is up and running at 10.0.2.0/24

#### iptables configuration

- `iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

### VPN logic

- When I receive an IP packet destined to an address, say `1.2.3.4`, I update it's destination to `127.0.0.1` and destination port to `12345`.
- I recalculate the checksum for both `TCP` and `IP` layer

#### Code

- I parse IP layer and TCP layer using [gopackets](https://github.com/google/gopacket)
- Update the destination port and ip address
- Create a NAT entry in the application layer, so that I can change back the `source_ip` and `source_port` in the response packets

```golang
// Code to receive packet from tun interface

    pkt := gopacket.NewPacket(packet, layers.LayerTypeIPv4, gopacket.DecodeOptions{
            NoCopy: true,
            Lazy:   false,
        })
        if ntPkt := pkt.NetworkLayer().(*layers.IPv4); ntPkt != nil {
            var err error
            if tPkt := pkt.TransportLayer().(*layers.TCP); tPkt != nil {
                // Adding NAT entry
                h.nLock.RLock()
                hash := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", waterutil.IPv4Source(packet).String(), waterutil.IPv4SourcePort(packet))
                if _, ok := h.natTable[hash]; !ok {
                    h.nLock.RUnlock()
                    h.nLock.Lock()
                    h.natTable[hash] = net.TCPAddr{IP: waterutil.IPv4Destination(packet), Port: int(waterutil.IPv4DestinationPort(packet))}
                    h.nLock.Unlock()
                } else {
                    h.nLock.RUnlock()
                }
                buf := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
                ntPkt.DstIP = h.proxyIP
                tPkt.DstPort = layers.TCPPort(h.proxyPort)
                tPkt.SetNetworkLayerForChecksum(ntPkt)
                err = gopacket.SerializeLayers(buf, h.opts,
                    ntPkt,
                    tPkt)
                if err != nil {
                    logger.E("Error while serializing, skipping the changes", err)
                    return nil
                }
                copy(packet, buf.Bytes())               
            }
        }

// Code to write packet onto tun interface
```

### Expected Output

- Traffic from `tun0` will be forwarded onto `eth0` (even if I don't add that iptable entry, default route will do the same thing)
- `eth0` will be knowing the lo addresses, so will forward the packet to loopback address, and eventually to the proxy running on the localhost

### Actual Output

- Packets are lost in-between
- `tshark -i tun0` shows the packets going out from `tun0`

```
2419 279.256438200     10.0.2.3 ? 127.0.0.1    TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47129 ? 12345 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=550203836 TSecr=0 WS=256
```

- But neither `lo` or `eth0` shows the corresponding entry for --dport 12345.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

- Network config was alright.
- Serialization of packets was wrong through go code
- Wrong code

```golang
err = gopacket.SerializeLayers(buf, h.opts,
                    ntPkt,
                    tPkt)
```

```golang
err = gopacket.SerializePacket(buf, h.opts, pkt)
```